# como puedo llenar un array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, array, local-storage

Hola quiero llenar el un array que le puse slider con la variable num y puse la variable num en slider pero igual no función que método tengo que utilizar para poner num  en slider.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//aqui es donde se pone el valor del id que se agarro

       $.ajax({
            url: 'recuperacion.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async:true,

            success: function(response){

            let info = JSON.parse(response);  

            let array =  info;  

            console.log(array);

            localStorage.setItem('los', array);
           
            },

            error: function(error) {

                console.log(error);
            },
                
        });    
 
    //comienso de la funcion de slider

    let num = localStorage.getItem('los');

    alert(num);

    let slider = [num];
 
    slider.forEach(function(elemento, indice, array){
  
    let slider_id = elemento;

    });

    return false

});
```

tambien trate de poner la variable let slider a const y en el array poner ...num pero igual no funciona

Comment: Necesitas mover todo dentro de `success`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hago aqui es cambiar success y error por 2 funciones, para poder separar el codigo y entenderlo un poco mejor.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'recuperacion.php',
        type: 'POST',
        async:true,
        success: handleSuccess
        error: console.log
    });
```

Esta funcion se va a llamar cuando te llegue una respuesta...

```
 function handleSuccess(response){
   // Creo un array del tamano de el numero que venga en la respuesta.
   const array = Array.from({ length: JSON.parse(response) });  
   // Itero el array
   array.forEach(function(ele, index){
       let slider_id = ele;
   });
}
```

Como veras, me pude saltar todos los localStorage.setItem que realmente los estabas usando de mala practica.

Comment: Gracias me sirvio